# Count Number of times each grade appears in a file

Tags: python

I am trying to print out the number of times each grade appears in a file.
score = [89, 45, 67, 78, 98, 0] * This can change for different files, can gain more numbers etc.

low and high scores have already been figured out. I only need to display the scores between them. 
What am I missing?
It isnt counting the numbers, just printing out this...

```
38: 0

39: 0

40: 0

41: 0

42: 0

43: 0

44: 0

45: 0

46: 0

47: 0

48: 0

49: 0

50: 0

51: 0


52: 0

53: 0

54: 0

55: 0

56: 0

57: 0

58: 0

59: 0

60: 0

61: 0

62: 0

63: 0

64: 0

65: 0

66: 0

67: 0

68: 0

69: 0

70: 0

71: 0

72: 0

73: 0

74: 0

75: 0

76: 0

77: 0

78: 0

79: 0

80: 0

81: 0

82: 0

83: 0

84: 0

85: 0

86: 0

87: 0

88: 0

89: 0

90: 0

91: 0

92: 0

93: 0
```

Any the code is:

```
def histogram(score, low, high):
    e = int(low)
    o = int(high)
    for i in range(e, o):
        print(str(i)+": "+str(score.count(i)))
    print()
```

Comment: Is this your only code? Because the problem does not seem to be here. Did you try printing the `score` list?

Comment: ['89', '45', '67', '78', '98', '0'] that is what prints out when I print the score list

Comment: Try `str(score.count(str(i)))` maybe

Comment: Can you give the data in file and can you be more clear.. cause I cant figure out any thing from this one...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your scores array is a list of strings. Either map it to a list of integers:

```
score = map(int, score)
```

Or count the string value at each step:

```
print(str(i)+": "+str(score.count(str(i))))
```

Comment: Better convert to int's; otherwise 9 > 89.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for. "Frequency of the list"

```
import collections
score = [89, 45, 67, 78, 98, 0]
counter=collections.Counter(score)

print(counter)
# Counter({0: 1, 98: 1, 67: 1, 89: 1, 45: 1, 78: 1})

print(counter.most_common())
# [(0, 1), (98, 1), (67, 1), (89, 1), (45, 1), (78, 1)]
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, but I am not able to use the collections library. Megawac has since helped me out. Thank you again